# Spring Cron expression to exclude running job on one day for set times

Tags: spring, cron

I have a job that gets submitted every hour at 15 minutes past each hour via a Spring cron expression.  A requirement has come up where this job is to not run at 12:15 am and 1:15 am on a Sunday morning.

My question is ... does cron support this kind of scenario where a job is to run every hour at 15 minutes past the hour except for 12:15 am and 1:15 am on a Sunday? Below is the expression that prevents it from running at 12:15 am and 1:15 am every day and it needs to be adjusted to only not run on Sunday at those times.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 2-23 * * ?")
```

Hopefully the above is clear.  If not, please let me know and I will provide additional information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 2-23 * * SUN")
```

Comment: Jens - thanks for your prompt response on my question.  If I read the above correctly that is going to run the job only on Sunday for the stated times.  Unfortunately I need that plus the job to run on all other days at 15 minutes past the hour.  Based on feedback from a co-worker it looks like I will need to have two expressions to accomplish what I am looking for... the first being what I listed in my initial post and the second being what you listed.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If it is wanted to run the job two specific days, it is possible to write the days together with comma.

Example: `@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 2-23 * * SUN,MON)`

Additionally, if you want to include all weekdays MON-FRI can be used:

Example: `@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 2-23 * * MON-FRI)`